# Is it semantically correct to use h2 tag inside summary tag?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I am not sure whether is it correct to have `<h2>` tag inside `<summary>` tag.

Whether semantically it is valid to have `<h2>` or `<h1>` tag inside `<summary>` tag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The semantics would depend on the specific content you had and the context it appears in.

From a validity point of view, [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-summary-element) says:

> **Content model**:
> Phrasing content, optionally intermixed with heading content.

So, it is valid.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, it is allowed. But you have to style a bit with CSS to avoid wrapping. To test the aviabillity use the [W3-Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and use the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_summary.asp) as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML Summary usage</title>
</head>
<body>
  <details>
    <summary><h1>Copyright 1999-2014.</h1></summary>
    <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
  </details>

  <p><b>Note:</b> The summary element is not supported in Edge/Internet Explorer.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is about semantics. Why are you talking about CSS, and wrapping, and layout?

Comment: @BoldClock _ ... <h2> tag inside <summary> tag. _ Because the standard summary tag comes with a clickable arrow to open the details. With a <h2> Tag without css styling the arrow is above the heading and it looks not so neat. It was just a tip