# In HTML, how do I put a heading inside a summary without the arrow appearing above the text or vanishing?

Tags: html

I am trying to make a very simple expandable/collapsible chunk of text using simple HTML, like this:

```
<details>
<summary><h5>Click this!</h5></summary>
<p>lorem blabbersum etc. etc...</p>
</details>
```

Unfortunately, the  tag causes the summary text to appear below the clickable arrow rather than to the right of it on the same line. If I remove the  tag, like this:

```
<details>
<summary>Click this!</summary>
<p>lorem blabbersum etc. etc...</p>
</details>
```

then the arrow and text are again in the places I want them, but the text is obviously no longer in the h5 style. (The reason I am doing this is I want the Open Sans h5 style, and don't know how to get exactly that style by applying CSS to `<p>` text.)

I've tried adding

```
style="display: inline-block;"
```

to the `<summary>`, based on suggestions I've seen, but this causes the arrow to disappear altogether. How can I use `<h5>` inside `<summary>` and keep the arrow on the same line with the text?

Comment: Why do you want to put a h5 tag isndie a summary? That is semantically not correct. If you want the style of the h5, then apply it through CSS:  `h5 { display: block; font-size: .83em; margin-top: 1.67em; margin-bottom: 1.67em; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; font-weight: bold; }`

Comment: PS: "*Click this*" is not a headline nor an accessible or good text for a summary. A summary should be exactly what it indicates, a summary of the content within the details tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41227910/9731176 appears to contradict @tacoshy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, header elements like `<h5>` have a `display: block`; style, which makes them start on a new line, to ensure that the summary and the header appear on the same line, you should override that default style.

```html
<details>
<summary><h5 style="display:inline-block">Click this!</h5></summary>
<p>lorem blabbersum etc. etc...</p>
</details>
```

However, it's not semantically correct to use an `<h5>` tag within a  element. Instead of use a `<h5>` tag you should use css to get the desired visual effect

```html
<details>
<summary style="font-weight:bold">Click this!</summary>
<p>lorem blabbersum etc. etc...</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Using your first solution worked wonders, because I'd already had styles applied to headings which wouldn't have worked without using an `<h*>` tag. However, I'm using this in a Markdown document, rendering in VS Code's default Markdown renderer. It renders lines beneath the headings which stretch to the right of the page (on LTR text, at least) but this line solely extends to the end of the heading text with this style applied. Using `<summary style="display:block">` (or `inline`) just makes the arrow disappear.

Comment: I'm referring to a line like https://stackoverflow.com/q/16073323/9731176 describes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195329/how-can-you-hide-the-arrow-that-is-displayed-by-default-on-the-html5-details-e#comment67779352_6202729 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16073356/9731176 worked. Many thanks for your solution.